# invalid hash while generating hash for pay u integration with android

Tags: php, android, payment-gateway, payu, payumoney

i m having issue with integrating pay u payment gateway integrating with my android app. i m generating hash on my own server when i generate hash for given parameters and use it in my app, the api is saying invalid hash please help me to generate hash

My php code is:

```
 <?php
// Merchant key here as provided by Payu
$MERCHANT_KEY = "0MQaQP";

// Merchant Salt as provided by Payu
$SALT = "13p0PXZk";

// End point - change to https://secure.payu.in for LIVE mode
$PAYU_BASE_URL = "https://test.payu.in";

$action = '';
$make_op=array();
$posted = array();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    //print_r($_POST);
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    //echo " key-".$key."  value-".$value."\n";
    $posted[$key] = $value; 

  }
}

$formError = 0;

if(empty($posted['txnid'])) {
  // Generate random transaction id
  $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20);
} else {
  $txnid = $posted['txnid'];
}
$hash = '';
// Hash Sequence
$hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
if(empty($posted['hash']) && sizeof($posted) > 0) 
{
  if(
          empty($posted['key'])
          || empty($posted['txnid'])
          || empty($posted['amount'])
          || empty($posted['firstname'])
          || empty($posted['email'])          
          || empty($posted['productinfo'])
          || empty($posted['surl'])
          || empty($posted['furl'])       
  ) {
    $formError = 1;
    echo "in if block";
  } 
  else {
    //$posted['productinfo'] = json_encode(json_decode('[{"name":"tutionfee","description":"","value":"500","isRequired":"false"},{"name":"developmentfee","description":"monthly tution fee","value":"1500","isRequired":"false"}]'));
    $hashVarsSeq = explode('|', $hashSequence);
    $hash_string = '';  
    foreach($hashVarsSeq as $hash_var) 
    {
            //echo $hash_var;
      $hash_string .= isset($posted[$hash_var]) ? $posted[$hash_var] : '';
      $hash_string .= '|';
    }

    $hash_string .= $SALT;


    $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hash_string));
    //echo "hash string==".$hash_string;
    //echo $hash;
    $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
  }
  $make_op['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash']=$hash;
  $make_op['message']="successfully generated hash";  
  $make_op['status']=0;  

  echo json_encode($make_op);
} elseif(!empty($posted['hash'])) 
{
    echo "Hash is present";
    echo $posted['hash'];
    $hash = $posted['hash'];
    $action = $PAYU_BASE_URL . '/_payment';
    $make_op['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash']=$hash;  
    $make_op['message']="successfully generated hashs"; 
    $make_op['status']=0;   
  echo json_encode($make_op);
}

?>
```

My android Activity code for sending data is:

```
   public void generateHashFromServer(PaymentParams mPaymentParams)
    {
        nextButton.setEnabled(false); // lets not allow the user to click the button again and again.
        // lets create the post params
        Log.e("Demo","In genrate hash from Server");

        StringBuffer postParamsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.KEY, mPaymentParams.getKey()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.AMOUNT, mPaymentParams.getAmount()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.TXNID, mPaymentParams.getTxnId()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.EMAIL, null == mPaymentParams.getEmail() ? "" : mPaymentParams.getEmail()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.PRODUCT_INFO, mPaymentParams.getProductInfo()));

        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.SURL, mPaymentParams.getSurl()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.FURL, mPaymentParams.getFurl()));
        //postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.HASH, mPaymentParams.getHash()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.FIRST_NAME, null == mPaymentParams.getFirstName() ? "" : mPaymentParams.getFirstName()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF1, mPaymentParams.getUdf1() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf1()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF2, mPaymentParams.getUdf2() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf2()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF3, mPaymentParams.getUdf3() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf3()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF4, mPaymentParams.getUdf4() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf4()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF5, mPaymentParams.getUdf5() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf5()));
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.USER_CREDENTIALS, mPaymentParams.getUserCredentials() == null ? PayuConstants.DEFAULT : mPaymentParams.getUserCredentials()));

        // for offer_key
        if(null != mPaymentParams.getOfferKey())
            postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.OFFER_KEY, mPaymentParams.getOfferKey()));
        // for check_isDomestic
        if(null != cardBin)
            postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams("card_bin", cardBin));
        Log.e("Demo","postParamsBuffer ="+postParamsBuffer.toString());

        String postParams = postParamsBuffer.charAt(postParamsBuffer.length() - 1) == '&' ? postParamsBuffer.substring(0, postParamsBuffer.length() - 1).toString() : postParamsBuffer.toString();
        // make api call
        Log.e("Demo","postParams ="+postParams);
        GetHashesFromServerTask getHashesFromServerTask = new GetHashesFromServerTask();
        getHashesFromServerTask.execute(postParams);
    }



    class GetHashesFromServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, PayuHashes>{

        @Override
        protected PayuHashes doInBackground(String ... postParams) {
            PayuHashes payuHashes = new PayuHashes();
            try {
    //  URL url = new URL(PayuConstants.MOBILE_TEST_FETCH_DATA_URL);
    //  URL url = new URL("http://10.100.81.49:80/merchant/postservice?form=2");;

                //URL url = new URL("https://payu.herokuapp.com/get_hash");
                URL url = new URL("http://vasatech.in/er_app/PayUMoney/PayUMoney_test.php");

                // get the payuConfig first
                String postParam = postParams[0];

                byte[] postParamsByte = postParam.getBytes("UTF-8");

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postParamsByte.length));
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.getOutputStream().write(postParamsByte);

                InputStream responseInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer responseStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] byteContainer = new byte[1024];
                for (int i; (i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer)) != -1; ) {
                    responseStringBuffer.append(new String(byteContainer, 0, i));
                }

                Log.e("response",responseStringBuffer.toString());
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseStringBuffer.toString());

                Log.e("response",response.toString());

                Iterator<String> payuHashIterator = response.keys();
                while(payuHashIterator.hasNext()){
                    String key = payuHashIterator.next();
                    switch (key){
                        case "payment_hash":
                            payuHashes.setPaymentHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash": //
                            payuHashes.setMerchantIbiboCodesHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash":
                            payuHashes.setVasForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash":
                            payuHashes.setPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "delete_user_card_hash":
                            payuHashes.setDeleteCardHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "get_user_cards_hash":
                            payuHashes.setStoredCardsHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "edit_user_card_hash":
                            payuHashes.setEditCardHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "save_user_card_hash":
                            payuHashes.setSaveCardHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "check_offer_status_hash":
                            payuHashes.setCheckOfferStatusHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        case "check_isDomestic_hash":
                            payuHashes.setCheckIsDomesticHash(response.getString(key));
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }                    
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return payuHashes;


 }
```

I am using pay u demo code for android integration but i dont know  if i use there server for hash generation then it gives right hash they said they use MD5 with SHA512 and i tried same but its wrong hash...pls help me to solve this

Comment: Please share demo url which u are using

Comment: this is the url on my server :-http://vasatech.in/er_app/PayUMoney/PayUMoney_test.php

Comment: `$hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";` string will contains your `$txnid`, your email, amount instead of default `txnid,amount,...`

Comment: yeah but still data is same on both server and client side....i was trying to use it for demo data ..so if its works for that data then i am using this code for my data

Comment: What is udf here? @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your **Salt & key** to generate **hash** from server

Sample code to generate hash at server side:

```
    <?php

function getHashes($txnid, $amount, $productinfo, $firstname, $email, $user_credentials, $udf1, $udf2, $udf3, $udf4, $udf5,$offerKey,$cardBin)
{
      // $firstname, $email can be "", i.e empty string if needed. Same should be sent to PayU server (in request params) also.
      $key = 'gtKFFx';
      $salt = 'eCwWELxi';

      $payhash_str = $key . '|' . checkNull($txnid) . '|' .checkNull($amount)  . '|' .checkNull($productinfo)  . '|' . checkNull($firstname) . '|' . checkNull($email) . '|' . checkNull($udf1) . '|' . checkNull($udf2) . '|' . checkNull($udf3) . '|' . checkNull($udf4) . '|' . checkNull($udf5) . '||||||' . $salt;
      $paymentHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $payhash_str));
      $arr['payment_hash'] = $paymentHash;

      $cmnNameMerchantCodes = 'get_merchant_ibibo_codes';
      $merchantCodesHash_str = $key . '|' . $cmnNameMerchantCodes . '|default|' . $salt ;
      $merchantCodesHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $merchantCodesHash_str));
      $arr['get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash'] = $merchantCodesHash;

      $cmnMobileSdk = 'vas_for_mobile_sdk';
      $mobileSdk_str = $key . '|' . $cmnMobileSdk . '|default|' . $salt;
      $mobileSdk = strtolower(hash('sha512', $mobileSdk_str));
      $arr['vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $mobileSdk;

      $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk1 = 'payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk';
      $detailsForMobileSdk_str1 = $key  . '|' . $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk1 . '|default|' . $salt ;
      $detailsForMobileSdk1 = strtolower(hash('sha512', $detailsForMobileSdk_str1));
      $arr['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $detailsForMobileSdk1;

      //used for verifying payment(optional)  
      $cmnVerifyPayment = 'verify_payment';
      $verifyPayment_str = $key . '|' . $cmnVerifyPayment . '|'.$txnid .'|' . $salt;
      $verifyPayment = strtolower(hash('sha512', $verifyPayment_str));
      $arr['verify_payment_hash'] = $verifyPayment;

      if($user_credentials != NULL &amp;&amp; $user_credentials != '')
      {
            $cmnNameDeleteCard = 'delete_user_card';
            $deleteHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameDeleteCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $deleteHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $deleteHash_str));
            $arr['delete_user_card_hash'] = $deleteHash;

            $cmnNameGetUserCard = 'get_user_cards';
            $getUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameGetUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $getUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $getUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['get_user_cards_hash'] = $getUserCardHash;

            $cmnNameEditUserCard = 'edit_user_card';
            $editUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameEditUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $editUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $editUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['edit_user_card_hash'] = $editUserCardHash;

            $cmnNameSaveUserCard = 'save_user_card';
            $saveUserCardHash_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnNameSaveUserCard . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $saveUserCardHash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $saveUserCardHash_str));
            $arr['save_user_card_hash'] = $saveUserCardHash;

            $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk = 'payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk';
            $detailsForMobileSdk_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdk . '|' . $user_credentials . '|' . $salt ;
            $detailsForMobileSdk = strtolower(hash('sha512', $detailsForMobileSdk_str));
            $arr['payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash'] = $detailsForMobileSdk;
      }


      // if($udf3!=NULL &amp;&amp; !empty($udf3)){
            $cmnSend_Sms='send_sms';
            $sendsms_str=$key . '|' . $cmnSend_Sms . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $salt;
            $send_sms = strtolower(hash('sha512',$sendsms_str));
            $arr['send_sms_hash']=$send_sms;
      // }


      if ($offerKey!=NULL &amp;&amp; !empty($offerKey)) {
                  $cmnCheckOfferStatus = 'check_offer_status';
                        $checkOfferStatus_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnCheckOfferStatus . '|' . $offerKey . '|' . $salt ;
                  $checkOfferStatus = strtolower(hash('sha512', $checkOfferStatus_str));
                  $arr['check_offer_status_hash']=$checkOfferStatus;
            }


            if ($cardBin!=NULL &amp;&amp; !empty($cardBin)) {
                  $cmnCheckIsDomestic = 'check_isDomestic';
                        $checkIsDomestic_str = $key  . '|' . $cmnCheckIsDomestic . '|' . $cardBin . '|' . $salt ;
                  $checkIsDomestic = strtolower(hash('sha512', $checkIsDomestic_str));
                  $arr['check_isDomestic_hash']=$checkIsDomestic;
            }



    return $arr;
}

function checkNull($value) {
            if ($value == null) {
                  return '';
            } else {
                  return $value;
            }
      }

$output=getHashes($_POST["txnid"], $_POST["amount"], $_POST["productinfo"], $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["user_credentials"], $_POST["udf1"], $_POST["udf2"], $_POST["udf3"], $_POST["udf4"], $_POST["udf5"],$_POST["offerKey"],$_POST["cardBin"]);

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

you can find more details from url : 
[PayU Documentation](http://achieveee.com/payu_documentation/custom-ui-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Hey man it seems like you are using your own server but you need to use your live salt and merchant key in php side just look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/32500376/3514144

Comment: this solution not going work in terms of  security stand point....you can't put your Salt into App like this ....they already menstioned it in there demo app...that thing is for testing else anyone can decompile the app to get the Salt

Comment: your key should go in the php side coding man not in android app

Comment: intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.SALT, salt); here they are passing  salt to nextActivity

Answer (score 0):

Here is the hash generation for pay u integration in java:

**Method: getHashes()**

```
public String getHashes(String key,String txnid, String amount, String productInfo, String firstname, String email,
String user_credentials, String udf1, String udf2, String udf3, String udf4, String udf5, String offerKey,
String cardBin,String salt) {
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
try {

//            sha512(key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||SALT)
//            hiESPS|7174761030002574230|12|product_info|firstname|xyz@gmail.com|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||xXZAKUi8
String ph = checkNull(key) + "|" + checkNull(txnid) + "|" + checkNull(amount) + "|" + checkNull(productInfo)
+ "|" + checkNull(firstname) + "|" + checkNull(email) + "|" + checkNull(udf1) + "|" + checkNull(udf2)
+ "|" + checkNull(udf3) + "|" + checkNull(udf4) + "|" + checkNull(udf5) + "||||||" + salt;
String paymentHash = getSHA(ph);
response.put("payment_hash", paymentHash);
response.put("get_merchant_ibibo_codes_hash", generateHashString("get_merchant_ibibo_codes", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash", generateHashString("vas_for_mobile_sdk", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash",
generateHashString("payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk", user_credentials,key,salt));

//for verify payment (optional)
if (!checkNull(txnid).isEmpty()) {
response.put("verify_payment_hash",
generateHashString("verify_payment", txnid,key,salt));
}

if (!checkNull(user_credentials).isEmpty()) {
response.put("delete_user_card_hash", generateHashString("delete_user_card", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("get_user_cards_hash", generateHashString("get_user_cards", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("edit_user_card_hash", generateHashString("edit_user_card", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("save_user_card_hash", generateHashString("save_user_card", user_credentials,key,salt));
response.put("payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash",
generateHashString("payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk", user_credentials,key,salt));
}

// check_offer_status
if (!checkNull(offerKey).isEmpty()) {
response.put("check_offer_status_hash", generateHashString("check_offer_status", offerKey,key,salt));
}

// check_isDomestic
if (!checkNull(cardBin).isEmpty()) {
response.put("check_isDomestic_hash", generateHashString("check_isDomestic", cardBin,key,salt));
}
}catch (Exception e){

}

return response.toString();

}

private String generateHashString(String command, String var1,String key,String salt) {
return getSHA(key + "|" + command + "|" + var1 + "|" + salt);
}

private String checkNull(String value) {
if (value == null) {
return "";
} else {
return value;
}
}

private String getSHA(String str) {

MessageDigest md;
String out = "";
try {
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
md.update(str.getBytes());
byte[] mb = md.digest();

for (int i = 0; i < mb.length; i++) {
byte temp = mb[i];
String s = Integer.toHexString(new Byte(temp));
while (s.length() < 2) {
s = "0" + s;
}
s = s.substring(s.length() - 2);
out += s;
}

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return out;

}
```